# Raycast algorithm fails to collide with diagonal walls in specific locations

Tags: algorithm, raycasting

I'm having a problem with my ray-cast algorithm in a 2D tile-based universe. I feel the situation would be best explained with a picture, so here it is:

[image]

The ray, represented by the blue line, is passing "through" the wall to hit its target when the wall passes through a point where the quantized line moves diagonally and the wall is perpendicular to it. The raycast function is as such:

```
def raycast(pos, direction, level):
    dx, dy = direction
    t=0
    x, y = pos
    obj=None
    while not obj and t < 5000:
        t+=1
        x+=dx
        y+=dy
        obj=level.get_at((round(x),round(y)),True)
        pass
    return obj
```

Is there a simple, efficient way to eliminate this kind of edge case?

Comment: You should look at line rasterization algorithms since your world is quantized to a fixed grid.  You don't actually need continuous ray-tracing.

Comment: @MooseBoys Line drawing algorithms are generally happy to take diagonal steps and don't solve the situation that this question is about.

Comment: @MooseBoys I'm also not really sure how line-drawing algorithms are an appropriate substitute for ray-tracing anyhow. I'm still going to need to look at every point along the line to see if there's something there, aren't I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do given your existing code, assuming there are no other complications, is to check both on the dx step and the dy step.

```
def get(x, y):
    # minimize code duplication
    return level.get_at((round(x), round(y)), True)

while t < 5000:
    t += 1
    x += dx
    obj = get(x, y)
    if obj: break
    y += dy
    obj = get(x, y)
    if obj: break
```

This has a tiny cost: it may unnecessarily check the same tile twice. If you later need to deal with this (e.g. an effect that applies to all tiles in the path of the ray) then you can just check if the rounded coordinates changed or not before doing anything.

If for whatever reason you need a more general and precise solution, you might be interested in [my answer discussing a 3D voxel raycasting algorithm](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/49423/9825), which precisely simulates a ray with arbitrary origin and direction and reports every time it passes through a face of a voxel (moving from one tile to another). The algorithm shown can be applied to 2D simply by changing the 3D vectors to 2D and removing the conditions for the Z direction.