# C++ Ray Traversing in 3D Voxel game

Tags: c++, c, raytracing

I'm currently working on a Voxel game in 3D and need a tad bit of help to figure out what Voxel the player is looking at. This is the data I currently have:

```
GRRLIB_Camera3dSettings(Player.x, Player.y, Player.z + 4, 0,0,1, Player.x + Camera.lookx,Player.y + Camera.looky,Player.z + Camera.lookz);
```

And the two 3d arrays that contains the player cords and block cords:

```
struct Player{
  int X;
  int Y;
  int Z;
}
int World[X_MAX][Y_MAX][Z_MAX];
//The cords are ALWAYS positive. ( and the array data: 0 Means air, anything higher is solid), The player
```

(GRRLIB camera is described here: http://grrlib.santo.fr/doc/group___all_func.html#ga7300940a38526ab5aa9be0f4abe4a32a)

So what I basically need to understand is how I would implement ray tracing using this data.
The whole project can be found here: https://github.com/filfat/WiiCraft

***For clarification* I am asking for a simple way in C or C++ to create a Ray tracing algorithm that would be used in a Minecraft like game for selecting the block the player is looking at, all data that is needed is above. So in short I need help to understand the math in a Ray Tracing algorithm and need a simple example so I could implement it myself.**

Thanks! :)

Comment: Please describe a bit more what you've tried and exactly what the problem is you're having now. How to implement an entire feature is a bit broad, so I'd suggest narrowing the scope if that's your question.

Comment: Alright, edited question to be more understandable.

Comment: this is called **traversing**. It is the most important and basic setup step before the actual ray/thing collision routine takes place, to reduce the potential collider's set. Some people uses **marching** as a specific case of traversal, which incrementally progresses in the partitionning structure, often using crazy SSE tricks for packet marching, when the structure is regular enough (grids..).

Comment: @v.oddou Didnt not know that, thanks for the heads up :)

Comment: People coming here from search engine, see also: [Cast ray to select block in voxel game](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/47362/cast-ray-to-select-block-in-voxel-game).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your world is represented as a grid, the algorithm you need to do line grid intersection is called [Digital differential analyzer algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_differential_analyzer_(graphics_algorithm)). The code too much to write quickly, you can find a full [explanation here](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/advanced-rendering/introduction-acceleration-structure/grid).

This algorithm/technique is used to solve different problems that need interpolating a variable over an interval. It's similar to [Bresenham line drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) algorithm but extended into 3D Grid.